# Formatting equations in LaTeX

Tags: latex

When I include an equation in LaTeX that is enumerated, i.e.

```
{\begin{equation}
$$
$$ ... \end{equation}
}
```

The line above the equation (blank space between the text preceeding it and the equation) is huge. How do I make it smaller?

Comment: What are the `$$` blocks for? Don't these make blank lines? Maybe put an example equation in your code. I'm confused.

Comment: +1 surprising, to me at least.  I've asked a follow-up question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897126/putting-s-in-the-middle-of-an-equation-environment-why-doesnt-latex-complai

Answer (score 4):

Your code it's a little bit messy. If you want to write math in your LaTeX code there are mainly three ways:

**Inline math:** include your math code between two `$` (like `$\pi=3,141$`); your equation or symbols will be displayed on the current line.

**Displayed, unnumbered math:** include your math code between `\[` and `\]` in the following way:

```
some text
\[
\pi=3.141
\]
some text
```

The equation will be displayed, but without a number for referencing it.

**Displayed, numbered math:** use the `equation` environment:

```
some text
\begin{equation}
\pi=3.141
\end{equation}
some text
```

The equation will be displayed and numbered.

If you have troubles with space before and after your equations, be sure of leaving no blank lines before or after the environment (as shown in the examples). Last remark: use of `$$` for displayed math is deprecated.

Comment: I don't know what the situation was in 2010, but these days unnumbered equations are best done with `\begin{equation*} ... \end{equation}` from `amsmath` rather than `\[ ... \]`.  For more details, see  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69854/77508

Answer (score 3):

As you wrote it I understand your example like that:

```
{\begin{equation}
 $$
 $$
 \tan x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}
\end{equation}
}
```

At first, you don't need the outer brackets.

What that code says to LaTeX is begin equation, end it, begin it again, typeset definition of tangens and end the equation.

If you want some gap before equation try:

```
...some code...
\vspace{1ex}
\begin{equation}
 ...equation...
\end{equation}
```

or define new environment in preamble. Something like this:

```
\newenvironment{myequation}{
 \vspace{1ex}
 \begin{equation}
}{
 \end{equation}
}
```

and in code use `myequation` instead of `equation`.

Comment: +1 Surprisingly, to me at least, "What that code says to LaTeX is begin equation, end it, begin it again" seems to be true: the space between the two $$s is typeset in textmode.  Shouldn't Latex complain that $$ is being terminated by a `\end{equation}?

Comment: As written here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897126/putting-s-in-the-middle-of-an-equation-environment-why-doesnt-latex-complai/2897238#2897238

Code `\begin{equation}$$ $$\alpha\end{equation}` will be processed correctly but code `\begin{equation}\alpha$$` won't be processed.

Comment: How does one delete space after the equation after using a `chemmath` command inbetween the equation, without loosing the numbering of the `equation` command?